# Send channel through a channel with Go

Tags: concurrency, go, channel

I'd like to send a pointer to a channel through a channel. Is it possible in Go? How to define function that accepts such channel?

I tried:

```
func test() (chan *chan)
func test() (chan chan)
```

Comment: You don't really need the pointer .. channels themselves are what you might call "reference types" in Go. They aren't as light weight as a pointer .. but they are as light weight as a slice.

Comment: Sending channel ends through channels is termed 'mobile channels' in some circles. It is subject to Milner's Pi Calculus (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A0-calculus).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is always some type associated with a channel. Let's assume that the type is `T`.  A channel of T is:

```
chan T
```

A pointer to a channel of T is:

```
*chan T
```

A channel of pointer to channel of T is:

```
chan *chan T
```

A function accepting the channel of pointer to channel of T is:

```
func f(c chan *chan T) { }
```

Because channels are reference types, you probably don't need to use a pointer. Try using

```
 func (f c chan chan T) { }
```

<kbd>[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/uNCSI1-f7Z)</kbd>